# Deserializing objects with nested ArrayLists with Gson?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, nested, gson

So I'm having some trouble with deserializing some JSON that has nested ArrayLists the root element deserializes okay but the nested ArrayList inside of it (Called mTest) are of null value. First here is the valid JSON.

```
[
{
    "mRecipeName": "FirstRecipe",
    "mTest": [
        {
            "mIngredientName": "TestIngredient1",
            "mIngredientAmount": "1",
            "mUnit": "tbsp"
        },
        {
            "mIngredientName": "TestIngredient2",
            "mIngredientAmount": "2",
            "mUnit": "tbsp"
        }
    ],
    "mRecipeDescription": "Recipe1"
},
{
    "mRecipeName": "SecondRecipe",
    "mTest": [
        {
            "mIngredientName": "TestIngredient1",
            "mIngredientAmount": "1",
            "mUnit": "tbsp"
        },
        {
            "mIngredientName": "TestIngredient2",
            "mIngredientAmount": "2",
            "mUnit": "tbsp"
        }
    ],
    "mRecipeDescription": "Recipe2"
    }
]
```

Here is the Recipe Class

```
public class Recipe {

    public String mRecipeName; //This values good
    public String mRecipeDescription; //This values good
    public ArrayList<Test> mTest; //This returns null
}
```

Here is the Test Class

```
public class Test {

    public String mIngredientName;
    public float mIngredientAmount;
    public String mUnit;
}
```

And here is how I'm calling it

```
//Is there another way to do this? Or does this have to be done for every nested
//ArrayList? If so how?

Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Recipe> result = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Recipe>>() {}.getType());
```

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who replies!

Answer (score 0):

So after another hour of hair tearing I realized that "Test" was coming from the JUnit framework and not my own test class, oh the agony! However, what led me to make a test class in the first place was the fact that it wasn't working and of course mysteriously now it is.